# Weird array index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, android, audio-recording, indexoutofboundsexception

There is something weird on my app that I don´t get to understand.

I am implementing an algorithm that detects when an impulse response has been produced (when the intensity value its above 0,2), and when it is detected, it stores the 0,5 sec of samples prior to the impulse stimulation and the 1,5 sec after the impulse.
Before I detect the impulse, all the samples are stored in a ring buffer of 0,5 sec long, and when I produce the impulse, the next samples are stored in a normal array of 2 secs long letting some space to later copy the 0,5 sec samples of the ring buffer.

The problem is that the code works pretty good sometimes, and other times it gives me array index out of bounds exception like this:

```
07-07 13:31:47.312: E/AndroidRuntime(28823): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16384; index=16384
07-07 13:31:47.312: E/AndroidRuntime(28823):    at com.example.acoustics.GrabaAudio.calculateImpulseLevel(GrabaAudio.java:174)
```

I don´t really see where in my code can this out of array bounds exception be produced so thats what I don´t understand. 
Buffersize is 8192.

```
 private byte[] calculateImpulseLevel(byte[] array){
            byte[] circBuffer=new byte[bufferSize*2];
            for (int i=0; i<=array.length-3 ;i+=2){
            double sampleAmpl=(double)Math.abs((array[i+1] << 8 | array[i] & 0xff)/32767.0);
            if (sampleAmpl<0.2 && !triggered){
                int s=circ.size();
                if (s<circCapacity){
                    circ.add(array[i]);
                    circ.add(array[i+1]);
                } else {
                    circ.remove(0);
                    circ.add(array[i]);
                    circ.remove(0);
                    circ.add(array[i+1]);
                } 
            } else{
                    if(!triggered){
                        triggered=true;
                    }
                    indice = indice2+(bufferSize/2);//Empieza a poner en el array a partir de 0,5 seg de muestras
                    circBuffer[indice]=array[i];
                    circBuffer[indice+1]=array[i+1];
                    indice2+=2;
                    //if (indice >=((2*bufferSize)-3)){
                    if (indice2 >=((3*bufferSize)/2)-3){
                        i=array.length-2;
                    }

            }
            }

        System.arraycopy(toByteArray(circ),0,circBuffer,
              0,circ.size());
        //circ.removeAll(circ);
        return circBuffer;
    }
```

As this error happens just some times and, normally, when I first compile my app  device it works pretty good and it gets worse and worse the more I run my app, I thought it might be caused by some garbage stored in the variables that are not properly erased after being used.

What do you guys think?

---

Ok, I have made some changes in the code and I have solved the problem of the index array out of bounds exception.

This is the piece of code that I have changed:

```
if(!triggered){
                        triggered=true;
                    }
                    indice=indice2+(bufferSize/2);
                    if (indice>2*bufferSize-2){
                        i=array.length;
                    }else{
                    circBuffer[indice]=array[i];
                    circBuffer[indice+1]=array[i+1];
                    indice2+=2;
                    }
                    /*if (indice >=2*bufferSize-3){
                        i=array.length;
                    }*/

            }}
```

Now I have a new problem, when I run my app in debugger mode everything goes perfectly but, when I just try to run it normally on my device, the audio array obtained appears as duplicated and it detects the impulse reponse always at 0,20 aprox and its duplicated version at 1,20 aprox as I show in the image below:

[image]
<sub>(source: [subirimagenes.com](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/8987227screenshot2014070915.png))</sub>

This is what I get in debugger mode and actually what I expect to obtain always:

[image: image2]
<sub>(source: [subirimagenes.com](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/8987236screenshot2014070915.png))</sub>

Why is this happening? and why just in normal mode and not in debugger?

Comment: what is at line 174 of `GrabaAudio.java` ?

Comment: circBuffer[indice]=array[i];

Comment: I am aware of that. The problem is that the way I coded it, apparently that situation should never happen, but it does, and I don´t know what I am missing.

Comment: `length=16384; index=16384` index should be 16383.

Comment: indice2 is just a local variable initialized to 0. It will go up to ((3*bufferSize)/2)-3 to ensure I don´t reach an array out of bounds exception

Comment: With the data you provided you shouldn't be getting this error at all.  Indice is most likely going out of bounds which are bufferSize*2.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Faith, methinks your comment was pretty obvious in part, and lacking other good proposals, since 42 would be another useful index value. ;-) Let's leave it at that, OK?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I'm sorry if I offended you.

Comment: @paviflo You'll need more data to track  this down. Add a handler and display all relevant values, including a save to the pertaining class variables at the time of the call of this method. (BTW, isn't this fumbling with bytes that make up unsigned shorts rather bothersome? Conversion to int would avoid all this 2* and *3/2 noise.

Comment: I keep them as bytes because later they have to be moved into a FileOutputStream to create a wav file.

Comment: I have edited the question cause I am facing a new problem now

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<=array.length-3 ;i+=2)
```

Let's say array.lenght is 100, then last index is 99. The condition would then be `i<=97`.

Last iteration will have i=96. And the highest index of array that will be used is: 97 which is inside the bounds.

Based on your provided data, variable's `Indice` max used index is:

`((3*bufferSize)/2)-3+(bufferSize/2)` Which is equal to `2*bufferSize - 3`

And that is 2 lower than it's bounds (bufferSize*2).

Everything seems to be in order. Indice2 is probably not what you made us think it is. You may want to try and set bufferSize to be 1 byte more, i.e. `byte[] circBuffer=new byte[bufferSize*2+1];`

As 16384 is the 8192*2.